# Exception while querying HTML for ID using HTML Agility Pack

Tags: html, xpath, parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm using the HTML Agility pack to parse an ASPX file inside Visual Studio.

I'm searching for an element with a specified ID attribute.

The code I'm using is:

```
var html = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
html.LoadHtml(docText);
if (html.DocumentNode != null)
{
     try
     {
          var tagsWithId = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(string.Format("//[@id='{0}']", selector.Id));
```

However, when I run this code it throws the exception "Expression must evaluate to a node-set".

Can anyone tell me why this "*must*" evaluate to a node-set? Why can't it simply return no nodes (the next line calls tagsWithId.Count)? Surely the HtmlNodeCollection that is returned by the SelectNodes method can contain 0 nodes?

Or is the error due to a malformed Xpath expression? [The selector ID which I'm testing this with definitely exists in the file as <div id="thisId">.]

Is it even possible to load an ASPX file straight from Visual Studio (I'm building an add-in) or will this contain XML errors, and will I instead have to load the output HTML stream (*i.e* without the page declaration at the start of the file, *etc*.)?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a detailed explanation and for the correct XPath expression to use. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The problem is in the argument to `SelectNodes()`:**

> ```
> //[@id='{0}']
> ```

(after carrying out the replacement) **is not a sybtactically legal XPath expression**. So the problem is not that the XPath expresiion "returns no nodes" -- the problem is that it is syntactically illegal.

As per the XPath W3C Spec:

"`//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`"

Thus the above is expanded to:

`/descendant-or-self::node()/[@id='{0}']`

Notice, that the last location step has no node-test and starts with the predicate. This is illegal according to the syntax rules of XPath.

**Probably you want**:

```
//*[@id='{0}']
```